# How to burn a cd (files not iso) from the command line in Windows 7

Tags: script, windows-7, cd-burning

I have used robocopy and a script to copy files from various resources. I now want to have my script automatically burn the files I copied to a cd. I'm looking for a command. I have tried xcopy but I keep getting an invalid drive error when trying to copy to the cd burner drive. I'm thinking I should be able to do this with a command or two, instead of having the script open up windows explorer, change to the folder, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the  Windows 2003 Resource Kit had two CLI programs to burn ISO images.
I once saw a program using these in order to burn a folder, but afaik it did not work with files.

A good program designed for burning via command line is [CreateCD](http://alexfeinman.com/CreateCD.htm).

This should do the trick, and probably is easier than getting [cdrdao](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cdrdao/) or [cdrtools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cdrtools) to work. Although they also have a good reputation ;-).

Additionally, popular burning freeware like [CDBurnerXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/help/appendices/commandlinearguments), [ImgBurn](http://forum.imgburn.com/index.php?showtopic=20061) support burning from a command line.

I also use ImgBurn.